# Number of Processor not match with CPUZ

Tags: c++, cpu-cores

I want to know the number of cpu core so, I thy this code

```
SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo;
DWORD getProcessorNum()
{
    GetSystemInfo(&siSysInfo);
    return siSysInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
}
```

It return 4. but when I check my result with CPUZ, it return 2Cores 4Thraeds

os I try __cpuid with this code

> unsigned regs[4];
>
> __cpuid(regs,4);
>   cores = ((regs[0] >> 26) & 0x3f) + 1;
>
> cout << " cpu cores: " << cores << endl;

It return 8 Core.

Could you please tell me, my code is wrong?

I run this code with MSVC++2010 on Win7x64 platform with i3 Processor.

Comment: CPUZ reports both hardware cores and logical cores. Seems, the Hyper-Threading is turned on on your machine and it will double number of cores (2 physical -> 4 logical).

Comment: @osgx: don't trust that page, it has many inaccuracies/obscure statements. when using cpuid, only ever trust the count returned from `__cpuid(regs,0)` and the data in the intel/amd developer manuals (edit: I see you change the comment/removed it)

Comment: Necrolis, can you say why cpuid 4 returned 8 as core count?

Comment: @osgx: you are misunderstanding my comment, it was referring to your now removed section about 4 being a valid cpuid index (`__cpuid(regs,0)` returns the valid indices to use with CPU id), as for why he gets 8, an i3 has 4 threads of execution, and its doubled by HT (as you say).

Comment: But CPUz says: "2Cores 4Thraeds"

Answer (score 0):

checking the amount of CPU's is not simple at all (mainly due to multi-core/socket/CPU designs). The `GetSystemInfo` call returns the amount of execution threads that the systems sees, CPUID has different values depending on the CPU topology (see the intel developer manuals).

I built something to catch all situations, you might find it useful:

```
static void GetProcessorTopology(size_t& nPhysical, size_t& nCores, size_t& nSystemThreads, size_t& nHWThreads, size_t& nThreadsPerCore)
{
    int nInfo[4];
    SYSTEM_INFO pSystemInfo;
    IsWOW64() ? GetNativeSystemInfo(&pSystemInfo) : GetSystemInfo(&pSystemInfo);
    nSystemThreads = pSystemInfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;
    if(TestTopologyLevel(nInfo,0x0,1) || TestTopologyLevel(nInfo,0x1,1))
    {
        nThreadsPerCore = nInfo[1] & 0xFFFF;
        if(TestTopologyLevel(nInfo,0x0,2) || TestTopologyLevel(nInfo,0x1,2))
        {
            nHWThreads = nInfo[1] & 0xFFFF;
            nCores = (nThreadsPerCore == 0) ? GetCoreCount(nInfo) : nHWThreads / nThreadsPerCore;
        }
        else
        {
            nHWThreads = nSystemThreads;
            nCores = GetCoreCount(nInfo);       
        }       
    }
    else
    {
        nThreadsPerCore = 1;
        nHWThreads = nSystemThreads;
        nCores = GetCoreCount(nInfo);
    }

    nPhysical = (nCores == 0) ? 1 : (nSystemThreads / nThreadsPerCore) / nCores;
}

static inline bool TestTopologyLevel(int* pInfo, int nMode, int nLevel)
{
    __cpuidex(pInfo,0xB,nMode);
    return ((pInfo[2] >> 8) & 0xFF) == nLevel;
}

static inline size_t GetCoreCount(int* nInfo)
{
    __cpuid(nInfo,0);
    if(nInfo[0] >= 4)
    {
        __cpuidex(nInfo,0x4,0x0);
        return (nInfo[0] >> 26) + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        __cpuid(nInfo,0x80000000);
        int nCPUID = nInfo[0];
        __cpuid(nInfo,1);                   
        if(nInfo[3] & 0x10000000 && nCPUID >= 0x80000008)
        {
            __cpuid(nInfo,0x80000008);
            return (nInfo[2] & 0xFF) + 1;
            }
        }

    return 1;
}
```